# How can i include common stuff in vars_files in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have these lines which i have to write in every playbooks

```
  vars_files:
    - "{{inventory_dir}}/common/vars/{{type1}}.yml"
    - "{{inventory_dir}}/common/vars/{{type2}}.yml"
    - "{{inventory_dir}}/common/vars/{{type3}}.yml"
    - "{{inventory_dir}}/common/vars/{{type4}}.yml"
```

Is there any way i can make them as some variable `common_vars_files` and use them in all playbooks

and then each playbook can define their own common_vars_files or use common

Answer (score 3):

If it's OK for you variables to be host-bound and not play-bound and `type1...4` is somehow predefined, you can place your vars files under `./group_vars/all/typeN.yml` and they will be automatically loaded as variables for all hosts.